# Magento Review and Rating - not showing

Tags: magento

I need help to show Review and Rating in backend admin navigation panel under catalog similar to link below:
http://www.hostknox.com/images/tutorials/magento/ratings-and-reviews/4-zoom.jpg

I have already checked below steps:

System > Configuration > Advanced > Advanced
- Mage_Review - Enabled 
- Mage_Rating - Enabled

No changes have been made to app/etc/modules/Mage_Review.xml

Is there anything else I can do so I can enable the above mentioned ratings?

Comment: Is your query regarding displaying the STAR RATINGS? or the Reviews as well? or Both? Also, whether it is backend or frontend or both?

Comment: Star Rating now showing at backend.

Comment: Is your problem solved?

Answer (score 0):

GO to Catalog=>Reviews and Ratings=>Manage Ratings

After that assign Rating Visibility for every fields. Then it will show on front-end and back-end.

Comment: Its not showing at the admin navigation panel backend. Thats my only query.

Comment: Front end is showing "Write your own review" but its not showing "Star Rating" review